# RestAPI naming convention for boolean endpoints

Tags: rest

It is a trivial question but I cannot find an answer. Lets say I have an endpoint that simply checks if a user exists within a certain group and returns a boolean. What should the RestAPI path look like?

`/api/user/{id}/exists/{group}`

`/api/user/{id}/in/{group}`

`/api/user/{id}/is_assigned/{group}`

`/api/user/{id}/exists_within/{group}`

I feel like the API path name should read organically, but I also don't like using an underscore. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing.  I have an endpoint that will simply return a boolean.  That seems to make it tough to follow naming conventions using resources/nouns.

Answer (score -1):

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your identifiers.

```
PUT /abff1822-71aa-4147-9b91-18a8a4f1bf6c
Content-Type: application/json

true
```

```
PUT /abff1822-71aa-4147-9b91-18a8a4f1bf6c
Content-Type: application/json

false
```

```
GET /abff1822-71aa-4147-9b91-18a8a4f1bf6c
```

Old school POST also "just works"

```
POST /abff1822-71aa-4147-9b91-18a8a4f1bf6c
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

value=true
```

URI are a lot like variable names - the machines *don't care*, and because they don't care you can follow whatever local spelling conventions make sense.